# Objective-C Does MPMediaPickerController Support Video Selection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was assigned a project in which I will be fixing a bug on a relatively old code base. It uses Cordova, Node, and AngularJS, so things are quite messy.

The user needs to be able to select an audio or video file from his/her device which will be sent off to a server. However, the MediaPicker does not display any of the videos in my phone's storage; only audio files are accessible (Yes, I have videos on my phone's local storage).

**EDIT:**
  The picker was initialized as seen below, with `initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAny`

```
  MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAny];
```

**EDIT #2:** The following screenshot is what i see regardless of the value for "initWithMediaTypes:"

[MPMediaPlayerScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB6Rm.png)

Simply put - **Has video selection been deprecated for the MPMediaPickerController?**

If so, what is the best alternative for selecting a video/audio file from the phone's storage?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes it supports video, you specify what media types you want it to include when you create it.

Comment: Please see my edit above

Answer (score 0):

According to apples documentation the MediaPicker still supports video content. Try initializing it to MediaPicker AnyVideo.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediatype?language=objc

Comment: Only problem with this is the fact that i need to support both audio AND video

Comment: Is AnyVideo showing anything? If it is then we could have one of two answers ether your audio files are not in the same place as your video files or your audio files are not recognized by the media picker.

Comment: I'm seeing the same screen regardless - please see my latest edit